# How to get a list item that is in another list to delete it on the first in Python 3

Tags: python, list, function, sudoku, solver

I'm new to Python, and I'm trying to make a sudoku solver. Now, I need to check if a number in a candidates list is in another list, and if it is, delete it from the candidates list.

```
line1 = [6,6,6,6]

def checkline(x):
candidates = [1,2,3,4]

if any(number in x for number in candidates):
    crap = int in x and candidates
    print(crap)
    candidates.remove(crap)
    print ("Works")
    print(candidates)
```

x = line1. I want "crap" to be the common number. How do I do it?

Comment: You should use sets for this, not lists. Then you can just check if the sets intersect. (Python sets here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Aren't sets unordered? Won't it be problematic with a sudoku, where order counts?

Comment: why do you need the candidates to be ordered?

Comment: I don't, but list "line1" must be. Can I work with it being the candidates a set and the line1 a list? Which method would work?  (thanks for the help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand the logic in your code but here is how you can "check if a number in a candidates list is in another list, and if it is, delete it from the candidates list":

```
candidates = [1, 2, 3, 4]
another_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]

for index, candidate in enumerate(candidates):
    if candidate in another_list:
        del candidates[index]
```

After running the code above, candidates will be `[2, 3]`.

For completeness (from a learning perspective), the code above can also be written without [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate), like so:

```
candidates = [1, 2, 3, 4]
another_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]

for candidate in candidates:
    if candidate in another_list:
        candidates.remove(candidate)
```

This is not the best way of approaching this problem but I thought it'll be easier for you to understand what the logic required is then you should re-think how you're solving this. At the least, using [Python's list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (instead of the `for` statements above) would be of great help here:

```
candidates = [1, 2, 3, 4]
another_list = [1, 4, 5, 6, 7 ,8, 9]
candidates = [candidate for candidate in candidates if candidate not in another_list]
```

Is this helpful?

Comment: Thank you! It really is. I know it's not the best method, but I'm really new, and thinking about another solution may be really time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than remove it from the list, consider creating a new list with the filtered items:

```
candidates = [i for i in candidates if i not in line1]
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna try it. I will see if it works better for me, or it confuses me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pehaps, you need something like this:

```
def checkline(line1,candidates):
    buf=[]
    for crap in candidates:
        if crap not in line1:
           buf.append(crap)
    return buf

candidates=checkline(line1,candidates)
```